# Joint::GetType() in Gazebo 1.x

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am porting a Gazebo 0.x plug-in to Gazebo 1.x. In the 0.x version, I had some code like this:

if (joint->GetType() == Joint::HINGE)
doSomething();

For the 1.x plug-in, I replaced the code with this:

if (joint->GetType() == Joint::HINGE_JOINT)
doSomething();

However, doSomething was never called. I ended up having to use this:

if (joint->GetType() == Joint::JOINT | Joint::HINGE_JOINT)
doSomething();

Is plug-in code now supposed to test individual bits of the value returned by Joint::GetType()? For example, should the plug-in now do this:

if (joint->GetType() & Joint::HINGE_JOINT)
doSomething();

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38316/joint::gettype()-in-gazebo-1.x/) by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 792 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the binary AND-operator (&) should work, but you can also use `Joint::HasType()` to test joint type, for example:

```
if (joint->HasType(Joint::HINGE_JOINT)) doSomething();
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0